# can i implement gps and/or speech recognittion in a hybrid app

Tags: android, cordova, gps, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM mobilefirst to implement a hybrid app. 
In my application, I need to have access to the mic so that I record the user's voice and retrieve his geolocation.
I have implemented this and tried it on the mobile first console and it works perfectly. However, when trying it on my phone (android os) it can get my gps location and doesn't record the voice.

I am using this for geo location:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    function showPosition(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log("LAT : " + lat + ", LONG : " + lon);
    alert(lat+"*****"+lon);
    }
}
```

If it's not doable this way, please suggest something else to get the same functionalities.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're showing the code that is working for you -  getting the GPS coordinates - instead of the code that is *not* working for you - recording voice... so the code snippets are of no use.

HTML5 audio tags will not work for you in a mobile *app*. To get it working you need to follow and implement this [using the Apache Cordova Media APIs](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.media), give the app required permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: the snippet  i shared (to get gps location) is not working on a mobile phone actually... also, i thought ibm mobilefirst insures the same functionalities as cordova! i'll try what you suggested anyway. thanks.

Comment: You have Cordova API to accomplish this as well.

Comment: would you please explain the relation between cordova and ibm mobilefirst?

Comment: MobileFirst apps are bundled with Cordova. Cordova is at the heart of MobileFirst apps.